# React: GET request launched by modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, get, dialog, fetch

**Problem**

I have a small problem with my GET request. **Each time** I open/close my form dialog or input something in it, the *GET request* I made with `fetch` and the hook `useEffect` get launched.

**Code**

```
import { handleErrorMessage } from "../App";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";

function Settings() {

  const userId = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

  let [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${userId}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", data.data.lastName);
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", data.data.firstName);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputs) => {
    inputs.addEventListener("input", () => {
      if (inputs.value.trim().length === 0) {
        handleErrorMessage(true, inputs.id, "Please fill the field!");
      } else {
        handleErrorMessage(false, inputs.id, "");
        if (inputs.value.trim().length < 12 && inputs.id === "deleteAccountPassword") {
          handleErrorMessage(true, inputs.id, "The password must contain at least 12 characters!");
        } else if (inputs.value.trim().length >= 12 && inputs.id === "deleteAccountPassword") {
          handleErrorMessage(false, inputs.id, "");
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <div id="settingsContainer">
      
      <button
        className="btn btn--blue btn--big"
        onClick={handleClickOpen}
      >
        Delete account
      </button>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Delete account</DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To delete your account, please enter your <b>password</b> and
            <b> confirm</b>!
          </DialogContentText>

          <input
            className="connectionForm__ipt"
            type="password"
            id="deleteAccountPassword"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            minLength="12"
            required
          />
          <p
            id="deleteAccountPasswordErrorMsg"
          ></p>
        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>
          <button
            className="btn btn--blue btn--big"
            onClick={handleClose}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>

          <button
            className="btn btn--blue btn--big"
            onClick={handleSubmitUserDeletion}
          >
            Confirm
          </button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the imported function `handleErrorMessage`  from the App.jsx:

```
export const handleErrorMessage = (isErroneous, inputsIDName, errorMessage) => {
  if (isErroneous) {
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").innerHTML = errorMessage;
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").setAttribute("aria-describedby", errorMessage);
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").setAttribute("role", "alert");
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName).style.boxShadow = "0 0 0.5em #9E0000";
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").style.color = "#9E0000";
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName).style.borderBottom = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").innerHTML = errorMessage;
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").removeAttribute("aria-describedby");
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName + "ErrorMsg").removeAttribute("role");
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName).style.borderBottom = "2px solid #135A71";
    document.getElementById(inputsIDName).style.boxShadow = "none";
  }
}
```

I'm new to React so I really don't know where I messed up, I tried various things but none of them really work...

At first, I thought it was because of my `document.querySelectorAll`, but it will only make sense when I type data inside the form dialog, not when I open it :/...

Anyway, I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me :).

P.S: For the code I posted, I tried to only keep the essentials, so while I checked multiple times, something may be missing. I apologize in advance for that.

P.S.2: The GET request has no problem in itself since I correctly got the data I asked for.

Comment: avoid using documents in React component, there are several ways to  do it without use the document.

Comment: Use the useRef instead document: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp

Comment: Is the fetch supposed to fire up only every time the app starts or when a particular event takes place?

Comment: Thank you @FabioRibeirodeCarvalho for your recommendations. I will remember them :D.

Comment: And to answer @SuryasishPaul, this fetch is supposed to only fire itself one time when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an empty array of dependencies to the useEffect in the following way should solve the problem:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${userId}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", data.data.lastName);
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", data.data.firstName);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  }, []);
```

This will ensure that the code within useEffect is run only when the app starts.

In any case, do let us know whether or not the change worked. Good luck!

Note: if the code seems exactly the same, check the last line of your useEffect where the brackets close.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will come back to you after trying :D.

Comment: Hey, I just checked your response in the question comments and I think you will have to place the code that is within useEffect within a conditional block. The condition being users' logged in state or something like that. What I need to now is, are you using open, setOpen to determine whether a user is logged in?

Comment: With useEffect, the number of times the code within the useEffect block runs depends upon the dependencies passed. No dependencies mean the code will keep running again and again infinitely (your initial code), empty array of dependencies means the code will run only once when the app fires up and X dependencies (like state variables) within the dependency array would run the code once when the app fires up and every time one/all of its dependencies change state.

Comment: To tell you the truth I didn't think about using a 'isLogged' variable, I should have... blame it on my lack of experience. Now, I will use this variable as a conditional block for useEffect like you recommended to me :D. 
By the way, thank you for the additional explanation about the empty array of dependencies :).